# Cómo crear un arreglo sin conocer el tamaño?

Tags: array, c

El objetivo es que el programa reciba un arreglo directamente, es decir, no recibiría el tamaño del arreglo, sino que directo los elementos del arreglo.

Por ejemplo:
Input: 1 2 3 4 5

Entonces mi pregunta es, cómo puedo crear un arreglo en lenguaje C sin saber su tamaño en primera instancia?

Comment: En realidad los arreglos pueden cambiar, no es algo desconocido, creo que te falta un poco de investigación amigo

Comment: Usa la función [realloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/). De hecho, la documentación tiene un buen ejemplo que te pueda ayudar.

Comment: `malloc` y `realloc`. Asignale un tamaño inicial, y ve aumentandolo conforme el usuario ingrese mas datos. Y no olvides liberar la memoria al final.

Comment: geeks4geeks tiene [un ejemplo](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/) de memoria dinámica que te podría servir.